# Copy current date(today) files using Ant Script

Tags: file, ant

I want to copy today's date log files from server using an Ant script. I have tried with following script but it is copying all the files from folder. But I would like to copy files like modified date is today's date.

```
<project name="MyProject" default="copy" basedir=".">
  <property file="${basedir}/build.properties"/>
    <tstamp>
      <format property="time.stamp" pattern="MM-dd-yyyy"/>
    </tstamp>
    <target name="copy" description="copy files">
    <echo>copying files</echo>
    <copy todir="D:\software\Files\${time.stamp}" >
      <fileset dir="C:\GatorNet\EAServer\logs" >
        <include name="**/*.log"/>
      </fileset>
    </copy>
  </target>
</project>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [date selector](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/selectors.html#dateselect) in your fileset.

Copying the example from that manual page:

> ```
> <fileset dir="${jar.path}" includes="**/*.jar">
>     <date datetime="01/01/2001 12:00 AM" when="before"/>
> </fileset>
> ```
>
> Selects all JAR files which were last modified before midnight January
>   1, 2001.

For your case, I think you want something like this:

```
<tstamp/>
<echo>${DSTAMP}</echo>
<mkdir dir="${DSTAMP}"/>
<copy todir="${DSTAMP}" includeemptydirs="no">
    <fileset dir=".">
        <date datetime="${DSTAMP}" pattern="yyyyMMdd" when="after"/>
        <include name="*"/>
    </fileset>
</copy>
```

Comment: Thanks...I copied successfully.

Answer (score 0):

```
<tstamp>
    <format property="TODAY_MY" pattern="yyyyMMddHHmmss" locale="en,UK" />
</tstamp>

<echo message="todaysDate: ${TODAY_MY}"/>

<echo message="Copy war files to Dir...."/>
<copy todir="/todir/">
    <fileset dir="/fromdir/"/>
    <globmapper from="*.war" to="*.war.${TODAY_MY}"/>
</copy>
```